# When memory space is reserved for struct?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

Is memory space reserved on declaration of following struct or when we create object of that struct?

```
struct student
{
    int marks;
    float average;
};
```

Comment: I think it depends on whether you use the data or not.

Comment: It is reserved when you instantiate an object. i.e. declaring a variable with `student s;` will reserve memory as will `student* s = new student();` but writing what you did only defines the type, it doesn't reserve memory as there is no variable being created.

Comment: Technically, in C++, you should use classes. Classes work just like structs, but have added features, like templates. The only reason C++ has structs is for backward compatibility with older C programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the `struct` the way that you did, there is no memory allocated for the structure. However, you can declare a `struct` *and* define a variable of that type right away, like this:

```
struct student
{
    int marks;
    float average;
} var_name; // Reserves the memory in the global/static space
```

You can also define variables in the automatic space (local variable) or in the dynamic space with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it should be when you create a definition. Since you can declare an instance of a structure without defining it (perhaps with extern in a header), no space will be used for an instance unless it is defined.

However the compiler can choose to strip objects out of a program if they are not actually used. Sometimes the compiler can be quite over-zealous and strip objects that aren't referenced at all, but actually perform important operations, such as some sort of registration.